# Password mismatch in Django production

Tags: python, django

My Django app works fine in development server but once I push it to production on heroku, user registration is giving password mismatch error. Could this be problem with heroku itself or my code(but I don't think so since it work well on my local machine)

Comment: Did you copy user data from development to production, or are users registering in production? Are you using the same `SECRET_KEY` in both places? (Best practice is _not_ to use the same `SECRET_KEY`, but that means password hashes won't be valid if you copy user data. Which IMO is also a good thing: there's no reason to be copying user data from dev to production.)

Comment: No, I did not copy user data from development to production, users are actually registering in production, but I did use same SECRET_KEY in production, could that be the problem? I really do need help right now

Comment: No, reusing a `SECRET_KEY` isn't ideal from a security perspective, but it shouldn't cause this. Are you using SQLite by any chance?

Comment: i dont think so because i include sqlite in the gitignore, so heroku shouldnt install it, what i do know is that heroku normally provide postgresql by default or do i have to manually connect the postgress to my app in settings.py if yes how do i do it?

Comment: ...no. First of all, that's not how Git's ignore system works. If a file is tracked, it's tracked. Ignoring a tracked file won't do anything. Secondly, Heroku doesn't magically convert your application to Postgres. You need to configure it. So I guess you _are_ using SQLite?

Comment: am actually a bit dumb on that i just saw my settings.py and i realize that its using SQlite `DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}` and checking my enviromental variable on heroku there is a variable named DATABASE_URL so can you give me a quick hint on how ill connect it in my settings.py

Comment: I'm not going to write an answer since this is too broad. But briefly: (a) I _strongly_ recommend switching to Postgres in development. These products aren't drop-in replacements for each other and I've seen several inconsistencies, including migrations that won't work in production. (b) You need to use that `DATABASE_URL` variable in your `settings` module. Checkout [`dj-database-url`](https://pypi.org/project/dj-database-url/) and (this one does even more) [`django-heroku`](https://pypi.org/project/django-heroku/). Also: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-app-configuration

Comment: (The answer to your question is probably that you are using SQLite. That doesn't play nicely with Heroku's ephemeral filesystem and you will regularly lose data, which would result in users not being able to log in.)

Comment: alright i actually already installed and use `django-heroku` according to this docs [link](devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-app-configuration) and `pip freeze` shows that ` dj-database-url`, whitenoise and all the other dependency for `django-heroku` are automatically installed, i think the only thing remaining is to do the actual connection of which dont have a clue

Comment: they claimed from the docs of `Django-Heroku` that automatic configuration is done including `DATABASE_URL`-------"This will automatically configure DATABASE_URL, ALLOWED_HOSTS, WhiteNoise (for static assets), Logging, and Heroku CI for your application."

Comment: If you've set it up correctly, yeah. If you connect to the database given by `DATABASE_URL` do you see your tables and data? (But this doesn't change the first point: it is _very strongly recommended_ that you switch to PostgreSQL locally. Don't expect your application to magically work on Postgres if you've developed it on SQLite. Sooner or later, this _will_ bite you.)